# Use Python pandas to check if coloumns contain identical values or NaN

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, equals

I would like a function that returns True if for each row in the columns, they contain only elements that are either the same as the elements in other columns or NaN.

Example:

```
A  B  C
1  1  NaN
4  NaN  NaN
2  2  2
```

The function should return `True` on this input

```
A  B  C
1  2  1
3  3  3
```

The function should return `False` in this input. (Since 1 and 2 or not identical, and neither are NaN)

EDIT:

`==` or `equals()` doesn't work, since:

1. it counts NaN as different from NaN
2. if I tell pandas to not do this is still counts NaN as different from 4.

Comment: This is my first post here, and I am not sure what I would be supposed to elaborate about.

I am also not sure how to approach this in pandas. If I don't get any new ideas, my way forward would be to solve it in pure python. Which I don't think is particularly interesting for stackoverflow.

Comment: Well did you try `df['A'] == df['B']`? Also your output needs explanation as I don't understand what return True and return False means here

Comment: I will make an edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea here is to count the unique values for each row in your data frame after excluding `NAN` values , if count is equal to `1` this means that your condition is fulfilled , other wise return false

```
df.apply( lambda x: len(x[-x.isnull()].unique()) == 1 , axis = 1).all()
```

then use `all()` that return `true` only if all rows satisfies condition